# Build Error - Roslyn MSB3883: Unexpected exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException for System.Security.Principal.Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I regularly receive the following during build in Visual Studio 2017:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Library, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error MSB3883: Unexpected exception: 

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : File name: 'System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CommandLine.BuildServerConnection.GetPipeNameForPathOpt(String compilerExeDirectory)

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(84,5): error : To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Nothing seems to consistently fix it.  Sometimes clean and rebuild works.  Sometimes restarting Visual Studio works.  But both have also seemed to have no effect so it seems more related to time or some other processes.

**Update**
I just tried upgrading from version 15.6.7 to 15.8.1 so we'll see if that fixes it.

**Update #2**
The issue has not resurfaced for me in version 15.8.1 but there are many reports in the comments that the issue still exists as late as 15.8.5.  The issue might not be version specific, but is instead some corruption that a reinstall or upgrade can sometimes fix.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I have the same issue that just started occurring today.

Comment: i have no idea - downvoting without comment is becoming a regular occurrence.  I will say I've not received the error since moving to 15.8.1 though.  If that fixes it for you I may post that as an answer but it's too early to tell on my own.

Comment: How about updating the Visual Studio to the latest version? Someone also have this issue on the old version 15.6.0, it could not be reproduce on the later version. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23563

Comment: I am getting this issue in 15.8.4 (the latest version as of now).

Comment: hmmm, maybe i need to unmark the answer then.  Maybe it is the act of installing a new version (or maybe even reinstalling) and not the version itself.  I have not received the error since upgrading.

Comment: After downgrading from 15.8.4 back to 15.7.6 the problem went away.  It was also a clean install (only way to downgrade I think), but I'm afraid to try to upgrade again.

Comment: I'm definitely having this issue in 15.8.5.

Comment: After a month, 15.8.1 is still ok for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrading from Visual Studio version 15.6.7 to the latest version solves this issue.

Comment: Just adding a note here to see the comments on the original question.  "Latest version" at the time of this answer was approximately 15.8.1.  People with later versions though are still reporting the problem, meaning either the issue found it's way back into the build or that something else resolves the prob (ie reinstalling regardless of the version)

Comment: I had left my build server at an old version of Visual Studio 2017 but ran into this issue today when getting it to build a new project (albeit very similar to the one, including .NET target & C# version) it has targeting for ages.

Logging on and running the VS installer to get the latest update fixed it (no reboot required)

Comment: Finally upgraded to latest, and this seems to have fixed the problem for me too! :)

Answer (score 3):

I have found that simply restarting my machine fixes this issue. I only get this issue on initial build of a project, this issue does not occur for me on existing solutions.

I have only managed to test this theory a couple of times so not sure it will work every time. But I thought I would post as it might same someone a bit of time.

This was with Visual Studio Enterprise version 15.8.6.

Comment: There were definitely times when I could get it to go away.  Sometimes clean and rebuild would work.  Sometimes deleting all bin an obj folders would work.  Sometimes restarting visual studio would work....but nothing consistent.

Comment: Using 15.6.6, my current workaround is deleting the packages and doing a "restore", which just fixed it for me

Comment: Amendment: I now don't restore, but instead just close visual studio, and wait for a minute. If I close and immediately re-open, it appears the error usually remains, so I expect it remains in some background process, that doesn't terminate immediately with the GUI.